# Adding module-info.java to the project results lombok errors

Tags: java, module, lombok, cannot-find-symbol, openjdk-11

I am trying to migrate from Java 8 to Java 11. My versions are as follows:

> 1. OpenJDK 11
> 2. Springboot: 2.2.7.RELEASE
> 3. Maven home: 3.6.1
> 4. Lombok: 1.18.12

Everything builds fine. Although I wanted to create a jre using **jlink** so I need to generate a `module-info.java` file. I generated it using the **STS** ide. I just right click on the `project -> Configure -> Create module-info.java`. When I did this, I can't build the project anymore. It throws a ***cannot find symbol*** error for the lines of code that calls ***@Data*** annotation of Lombok.

I've tried adding the ***annotationProcessorPaths*** tags as stated here: [solution](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1723) but it still does not work. I also tried adding the ***static*** keyword like this:
[image] but it still does not work.

This is what my pom looks like now:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <compilerVersion>11</compilerVersion>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <annotationProcessorPath>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.12</version>
            </annotationProcessorPath>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArguments>
            <AaddGeneratedAnnotation>false</AaddGeneratedAnnotation>
            <Adebug>true</Adebug>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've been searching for the whole day for a solution but I still can't find one that works for me. Any other suggestions that I can try?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I had the same issue with lombok, but adding `static` worked for me for some reason (I'm using Gradle with the badass-jlink plugin).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the plugin section that I've posted in the question, I just transformed it into this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.12</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

and it returned a build successful.